# jqGrid Enter key before save handler

Tags: jqgrid

I am using jqGrid 3.8.1 with inline edit mode. Users are currently allowed to hit the Enter key in order to save a row. I would like to let them continue to do this, but I need to do some data validation (including a call to the server) before they can be allowed to save the row. Is this possible? I don't see anything like a "beforeSaveRow" function that gets called in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server side validation is the part of saving the changes. The server get the modified data and it can send back HTTP response with some [error HTTP code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error) (some value higher or equal to 400). One can include the description of the error in the body of the HTTP response. jqGrid will display the error message and the user can continue the editing. One can use additionally `errorfunc` callback of inline editing to decode the server response holding the error and to convert it to some another HTML fragment.

Comment: Hey Oleg, so basically you're saying that the validation must be done on the server side? jqGrid does not provide any "on before row save" event?

Comment: @user1334007: You asked about server side validation. The client side validation can be implemented only on the column basis (validation of separate new value for the column) by [editrules](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#editrules) inclusive of [custom validation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#custom_checking_example).

Comment: sorry, I just meant that part of the client side validation process may involve making a call to the server to get some extra data need of the validation process. So you'd make a call to the server to do the validation, then if that passed you'd make another call to the server to actually save the row.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not interested in column validation. So i you can't do row validation I guess I might have to do all the validation on the server side.

Comment: @user1334007: Sorry, but exactly because of the formulation I wrote my answer. You should consider exactly what you suggest. You suggest that your client side code makes **separate additional Ajax request** and send the data which will be send immediately after the request. I see no sense in the behavior because it could be some validation errors (SQL constants like UNIQUE key, trigger or wrong character, wrong date and so on) during saving itself. I see no sense in two calls which both do practically the same and the user will see the same error message.

Comment: Yeah making it all happen on the save call is an option. Given the current architecture of the system (which I realize you don't have any knowledge of) it's actually a bit simpler to make two calls but since that's not really an option, I'll do all the validation on the server end. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @user1334007: You are welcome! If you think about the architecture of the system than it's important to remark that two asynchronous cascading calls to the server required absolutely another structure of callbacks. The usage of synchronous calls (at least the usage of `async: false` option in the first validation call) makes the user interface slowly. Because of that no additional server side validations are implemented in jqGrid.